# Django - Different forms for model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Depending on my models state, I want to show a different form to the user. I'm trying to figure out how I'd store a reference to the correct form so I can load it in my view.

An normal view would look like:

```
from myapp.forms import SomeForm

def view():
form = SomeForm()
```

However, since I don't know which form my model needs, how would I dynamically import the form class?

I tried this:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
modelforms = ModelForm.__subclasses__()

def get_modelform(model):
    return filter(lambda x:x.Meta.model == model, modelforms)[0]
```

But it only works if the form has been imported into the project. Since my form lives in it's own forms.py file, this doesn't work :(

Comment: What's the problem importing all forms and only using the one you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In your forms.py* file, write a function that returns the correct form according to your criteria. Then import that into your view and call it there.

Answer (score 1):

Write a function that returns needed form class according to the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use modelform fabric, it could help you to make forms for your models

`FormClass = modelform_factory(ModelClass)`

https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/models.py#L370